# Implement Enumerator.GetNext() extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ienumerable

I would like to implement a generic `IEnumerator<T>` extension method that returns the next element in the `IEnumerable` as followed:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();

var nextItem1 = enumerator.GetNext();
var nextItem2 = enumerator.GetNext();

// Instead of calling enumerator.MoveNext() and then reading the current item.
```

I tried to do this but it won't compile:

```
public static T GetNext(this IEnumerator<T> list)
{
     list.MoveNext();
     return list.Current;
}
```

Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What compiler error do you get?  Just saying you code won't compile doesn't give enough information as to what might be wrong.  Also, how is your class defined?

Comment: What should your `GetNext` return when `MoveNext` returns false?

Comment: An exception. See my last comment under the selected answer. It (tries) to explain the use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be missing the generic type definition on the method signature:

```
public static T GetNext<T>(this IEnumerator<T> list)
{
    // ---- this bit---^^^
}
```

It needs to be there assuming there is no class level generic type with the same name. Otherwise it looks fine.

*However...*

I personally wouldn't do it this way as you are not listening to the result of `MoveNext`. Unless you can make assumptions about the expected values, there is no way for you to tell if the iterator reached the end of the set. For most common uses, this won't be a viable approach.

I actually went the other route and implemented an `AsEnumerable` extension method that simply iterates manually, but from the outside allows you to do stuff like `foreach (var item in iterator.AsEnumerable())` and doesn't ignore the `MoveNext` result:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> AsEnumerable<TSource>(this IEnumerator<TSource> iterator)
{
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return iterator.Current;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right about not knowing when it ends the itteration but in my case i still need it to work this way. I'm using it to render a cshtml template with a table where the number of headers is defined in the HTML but each header loads its name from an enum Description attribute which is send via a list of enums. I'm just trying to avoid an overkill of creating a full blown Table ViewModel and have the table rendered completely dynamically while in the same time i want to have the names of the headers defined in one place (the enum attribute) because this same enum is used in other places.

Comment: @UriAbramson You might have a situation where your solution can work, because depending on the value you get back you might be able to test for when iteration has likely ended (such as encountering nulls). I just wanted to post the warning for other readers, which is why I held of saying "this is the wrong way". It isn't, it's just a way with limitations.